# Avoid SettingWithCopyWarning in python using iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Usually, to avoid SettingWithCopyWarning, I replace values using .loc or .iloc, but this does not work when I want to forward fill my column (from the first to the last non-nan value).
Do you know why it does that and how to bypass it ?

My test dataframe :

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':[11.1,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.5,11.6,11.7,11.8,11.9,12.0,12.10,12.2,12.3,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.7,12.8,12.9],
                   'test':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,22,8,np.nan,4,5,4,5,np.nan,-3,-54,-23,np.nan,89,np.nan,np.nan]})
```

and the code that raises me a warning :

```
df3['test'].iloc[df3['test'].first_valid_index():df3['test'].last_valid_index()+1] = df3['test'].iloc[df3['test'].first_valid_index():df3['test'].last_valid_index()+1].fillna(method="ffill")
```

I would like something like that in the end :

[image]

Comment: what you are trying to do? you are using iloc not in good way

Comment: @sygneto im trying to forward fill my column from the first to the last non-nan value

Comment: how about first 3 rows? leave it as nans or fill it backward? (take value from 4 th row)?

Comment: @sygneto that means that the first and the last nans are staying nans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `first_valid_index` and `last_valid_index` to determine range that you want to `ffill` and then select range of your dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':[11.1,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.5,11.6,11.7,11.8,11.9,12.0,12.10,12.2,12.3,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.7,12.8,12.9],
                   'test':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,22,8,np.nan,4,5,4,5,np.nan,-3,-54,-23,np.nan,89,np.nan,np.nan]})

first=df['test'].first_valid_index()
last=df['test'].last_valid_index()+1

df['test']=df['test'][first:last].ffill()
print(df)
    Timestamp  test
0        11.1   NaN
1        11.2   NaN
2        11.3   NaN
3        11.4   2.0
4        11.5  22.0
5        11.6   8.0
6        11.7   8.0
7        11.8   4.0
8        11.9   5.0
9        12.0   4.0
10       12.1   5.0
11       12.2   5.0
12       12.3  -3.0
13       12.4 -54.0
14       12.5 -23.0
15       12.6 -23.0
16       12.7  89.0
17       12.8   NaN
18       12.9   NaN
```

Comment: so you want to fill values until more than 1 nan exist?

Comment: from the first valid index to the last, check documentation here pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html